# How to display an empty string initially in a TextFormField allowing only Digits in flutter?

Tags: flutter, flutter-layout

I have a text field that allows only digits. But when my user adds a new model then I need to preassign a value to the field numberOfPets.

Only 0-9 is allowed so I could use 0 but I would rather have an empty string in that text field but that is not possible as String is not a subtype of Int... I have also tried `null` but that is literally written as initialValue.

How would you display an empty string in that textfield ?

```
TextFormField(
              keyboardType: TextInputType.number,
              inputFormatters: [
                LengthLimitingTextInputFormatter(3),
                WhitelistingTextInputFormatter.digitsOnly,
              ],
              decoration: const InputDecoration(
                labelText: 'reps',
              ),
              initialValue: widget.set.numberOfPets.toString() ,
              validator: (value) {
                return StringFieldValidator.validate(value);
              },
              onChanged: (value) {
                setState(() {
                  widget.set.numberOfPets= int.parse(value);
                });
              },
            ),
```

Comment: Not sure with what you want to achieve. You want to preassigned a value to numberOfPets and have empty String in TextFormField. That are two separate things, assign value to numberOfPets in initState and don't give initialValue to TextFormField. I can't understand your question

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Keep the numberOfPets as 0 but while assigning to initialValue check if 0 and change it to empty string

```
TextFormField(
    keyboardType: TextInputType.number,
   inputFormatters: [
      LengthLimitingTextInputFormatter(3),
      WhitelistingTextInputFormatter.digitsOnly,
    ],
    decoration: const InputDecoration(
      labelText: 'reps',
    ),
    initialValue: widget.set.numberOfPets ==0 ? '' : widget.set.numberOfPets.toString() ,
    validator: (value) {
      return StringFieldValidator.validate(value);
    },
    onChanged: (value) {
      setState(() {
        widget.set.numberOfPets= int.parse(value);
      });
    },
),
```

Comment: ah... now I see what the author wants to achieve, I thought that the preassigned value would always be 0 so I was getting little bit confused there.

Comment: i had the solution before with numberOfPets ?? ''; where pets can be null instead of 0, but still thanks :-)